# JSON returned from JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj) returnserro " Unexpected token & " in Json.parse

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, json, asp.net-core

```
model.DepartmentsList = list;
model.DepartmentsListJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model.DepartmentsList);
```

returns this `JSON` :

> "[{\"DeptNo\":\"d006\",\"DeptName\":\"Production\",\"FromDate\":null,\"ToDate\":null},{\"DeptNo\":\"d007\",\"DeptName\":\"Sales\",\"FromDate\":null,\"ToDate\":null},{\"DeptNo\":\"d009\",\"DeptName\":\"Customer
>   Service\",\"FromDate\":null,\"ToDate\":null},{\"DeptNo\":\"d021\",\"DeptName\":\"DEV\",\"FromDate\":null,\"ToDate\":null},{\"DeptNo\":\"d022\",\"DeptName\":\"Human
>   Resources
>   5\",\"FromDate\":null,\"ToDate\":null},{\"DeptNo\":\"d023\",\"DeptName\":\"Human
>   Resources
>   6\",\"FromDate\":null,\"ToDate\":null},{\"DeptNo\":\"d024\",\"DeptName\":\"Human
>   Resources 7\",\"FromDate\":null,\"ToDate\":null}]"

( Ignore the null values) . And when I try to parse it in javascript

```
var departmentsList = JSON.parse(@Model.DepartmentsListJson);
```

I got following message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
```

What should I use in order to return a valid `JSON` string from my `C#` code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
var departmentsList = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(@Model.DepartmentsListJson));
```

The problem is your mixing c# with razor and javaScript. So when you do this:

```
var departmentsList = JSON.parse(@Model.DepartmentsListJson);
```

Unless I am mistaken your accessing the object in c# and not the actual value that it contains.

Comment: It worked. I had to get rid of the JSON.parse because I was already sending an object but the @Html.Raw did the trick. Didn't know about this. Thank you!

Comment: @WarrenG You're welcome. I would advise against mixing javaScript with Razor as I find it a bit messy but I am glad it worked.